# Tracking a path of sd card file programatically

Tags: android, webview

I have put html file in sd card on android device. and i am running that through webview. But the path that i am giving in emulator is working fine. but not on device. Its giving an error ** Web Page on Found** while running.

I have this code to find the sd card availability and sd card root directory path and it is working fine. and output is coming properly.

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

        if(isSDPresent)
        {
          Toast.makeText(this, "yes SD-card is present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        externalStorage.getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(this, externalStorage.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but can i get the proper whole file path. Please suggest.

Comment: a proper filepath? whats wrong with the one you are getting now?

Comment: /mnt/sdcard i am getting for the root directory.But in device i don't y it is not running. giving an error of web page not found.thats y i wanted to track the whole path till where i put my file in sd card in device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code definitely solve your problem

```
String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
                       + File.separator
                       + vfile;
```

also if you want to add some files in sd card then use this permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this can be help you, try it.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Filename_with_extension" ;
```